# Joining values of two dicts by matching key value

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries like this:

```
dict1 = {'foo': {'something':'x'} }
dict2 = {'foo': {'otherthing':'y'} }
```

and i want to join the values together so that:

```
dict3 = {'foo': {'something':'x', 'otherthing':'y'} }
```

How can I do this?

Note: both dicts will always have matching keys.

Comment: what about unmatching keys?

Comment: The two dicts will always have the same keys but different values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> dict1 = {'foo': {'something':'x'} }
>>> dict2 = {'foo': {'otherthing':'y'} }
>>>
>>> {key: dict(dict1[key], **dict2[key]) for key in dict1}
{'foo': {'otherthing': 'y', 'something': 'x'}}

>>> # ---Or---
>>> {keys: dict(dict1[keys].items() + dict2[keys].items()) for keys in dict1}
{'foo': {'otherthing': 'y', 'something': 'x'}}
```

they just use two different ways to merge dicts.

Comment: FWIW: `dict(kwargs, **dict)` is a trick to merge two dicts that guido [dislikes](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-April/099459.html).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary. Yeah saw it. Actually, that's why I added another option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dic = defaultdict(dict)
for k in dict1:
    dic[k].update(dict1[k])
    dic[k].update(dict2[k])
...     
>>> dic
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>,
{'foo': {'otherthing': 'y', 'something': 'x'}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, as a shorter one-liner dictionary comprehension:

```
{ k : dict(dict2[k].items() + v.items()) for k, v in dict1.items() }
```

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done using for loops:

```
>>> dict3 = {}
>>> for x in dict1.keys():
        for y in dict1[x].keys():
            for z in dict2[x].keys():
                dict3[x] = {y: dict1[x][y], z: dict2[x][z]}

>>> dict3
{'foo': {'otherthing': 'y', 'something': 'x'}}
```